# check which ObjectID are done in ray

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ray

I have some remote functions in ray submitted for calculations. Before getting them with `ray.get` I would like to first check if they are done, so that I can continue doing other things while they compute.

Also I am really thinking of maintaining a dictionary with this structure

```
{
  { 'JSON of parameters used in the calculation': OBJECTid},
   ...
}
```

so that I can read through this dictionary perioically and collect the OBJECTid that are done. To do this I need to interrogate the tasks manager to know if an OBJECTid is completed.

At this [page](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) I seem to see interesting functions, e.g. the `ray.objects()` function. This, however, seems to not be available in my notebook although I see many of the other functions listed there, e.g. the `ray.init()`, `ray.shutdown()`, etc. All the functions listed in `Inspect the Cluster State` seems to be missing, maybe I am missing some important step (import?)

Comment: Regarding the functions in "inspect the cluster state" being missing. That's because wasn't quite in sync with the latest release. Ray 0.7.1 (which was released a couple days ago), should have all of those functions.

Comment: I just updated, I see `ray.objects()` now. Thanks for the tip and for making ray possible : )

Comment: By the way I see again the `AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'` due to `typing` being installed despite I am on python 3.7. I think this comes from a dependency of `modin` [issue](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/540) , not from ray itself, any chance can be avoided in the packaging of ray (just for our convenience)?

Comment: Does running `pip uninstall typing` fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, that works, once the issue becomes clear the solution is quite easy, but it took a while to understand where it was coming from and I think it affects all 3.7 users.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that the `ray.wait` functions does it. It's key to set the timeout to zero, otherwise is going to block the kernel.

```
ready_ids, _remaining_ids = ray.wait([OBJECTid],timeout=0)
```